# Linq crosstab and grouping

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, pivot

I have a set of data that looks something like this:

```
ItemID | ProcessID | Sequence
Item 1 | ProcessA  | 1 
Item 1 | ProcessB  | 2 
Item 3 | ProcessA  | 1 
Item 2 | ProcessA  | 1 
Item 1 | ProcessC  | 3
Item 3 | ProcessB  | 2
```

etc

I would like to create a linq query that formats the data like this:

```
ItemID | Sequence 1 | Sequence 2 | Sequence 3 | Sequence N 
Item 1 | ProcessA   | ProcessB   | ProcessC 
Item 2 | ProcessA   |  
Item 3 | ProcessA   | ProcessB
```

etc

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You can use [LINQ Extensions Library](http://linqlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pivot) to `PIVOT` your data.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan : Will this work with dynamic number of columns? What I can see he must do a `PIVOT` with dynamic sql

Comment: What I can see if you want to do it with dynamic number of columns. You have to do it in sql. What RDMS are you using (mssql)?

Comment: Yes MSSQL. I guess I could take a guess at the maximum number of columns if it makes the Linq work?

Comment: Or you can use the pure sql way. You can make a `Pivot` with just the number of Sequences you have. Otherwise you will have a lot of column that might be empty and it also might be harder to present in a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed the number of processes to avoid the dynamic columns. Not ideal but it will work for my application.

```
public static IQueryable GetProcessesForAllItems()
{
    var ctx = new CS3Entities();

    var allprocesses = (from pi in ctx.ProcessesItems
                        orderby pi.SequenceNumber descending
                        select new
                                   {
                                       pi.ItemID,
                                       pi.ProcessID,
                                       pi.SequenceNumber
                                   });

    var query = allprocesses
        .GroupBy(c => c.ItemID)
        .Select(g => new
                         {
                             ItemId = g.Key,
                             Seq100 = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SequenceNumber == 100).ProcessID,
                             Seq200 = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SequenceNumber == 200).ProcessID,
                             Seq300 = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SequenceNumber == 300).ProcessID,
                             Seq400 = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SequenceNumber == 400).ProcessID,
                             Seq500 = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SequenceNumber == 500).ProcessID,
                             Seq600 = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SequenceNumber == 600).ProcessID,
                             Seq700 = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SequenceNumber == 700).ProcessID,
                             Seq800 = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SequenceNumber == 800).ProcessID,
                             Seq900 = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SequenceNumber == 900).ProcessID,
                             //etc
                         });
    return query;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the pure sql way for solving this problem. So here is a suggesting for you:

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
    ItemID VARCHAR(100),
    ProcessID VARCHAR(100), 
    Sequence INT
)
INSERT INTO #T
VALUES
    ('Item 1','ProcessA',1), 
    ('Item 1','ProcessB',2),
    ('Item 3','ProcessA',1),
    ('Item 2','ProcessA',1),
    ('Item 1','ProcessC',3),
    ('Item 3','ProcessB',2)
```

**Columns for the pivot**

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Sequence ORDER BY Sequence) AS RowNbr,
    'Sequence '+CAST(t.Sequence AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Sequence
FROM
    #T AS t
)
SELECT @cols=STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT
            ',' +QUOTENAME([Sequence])
        FROM
            CTE
        WHERE CTE.RowNbr=1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )
,1,1,'')
```

Execute the dynamic pivot

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.ItemID,
        t.ProcessID,
        ''Sequence ''+CAST(t.Sequence AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Sequence
    FROM
        #T AS t
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ProcessID)
    FOR Sequence IN ('+@cols+')
) AS p'
```

EXECUTE(@query)

Drop the temp table

```
DROP TABLE #T
```